# C# iterate through text boxes and update value

Tags: c#, loops, textbox

Preface...I do not develop in C# much at all, so I am open to criticism on best practices.

I have a form that has roughly 70 sets of text boxes that are grouped within 6 group boxes. I have a method that takes the values from two of the text boxes and returns some values from a DB. Each set of text boxes contains an iteration of:

```
org1...org70
app1...app70
orgDesc1...orgDesc70
status1...status70
sent1...sent1
error1...error1
```

What I am attempting to do in the code below is start at set 1 and iterate through set 20 (the first group box), each time passing org and app to my query method and returning the 4 values to populate orgDesc, status, sent, error.

I have looked through other posts and I have tried to get a few to work but to no avail. I am posting what I currently have as an iteration but fails in the query method with null error when running the query. As a note, if I define the process statically everything runs perfect but I do not want to have 70 versions of the same process for no reason when it should be able to be done in a loop.

```
private void Refresh1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 1;
    do
    {
        string org = "org" + count;
        string orgIn = groupBox1.Controls[org].Text;
        string app = "app" + count;
        string appIn = groupBox1.Controls[app].Text;
        string name = "name" + count;
        string stat = "status" + count;
        string Sent = "Sent" + count;
        string error = "error" + count;
        string orgDesc, status, numSent, numError;
        NumSent1(orgIn, appIn, out orgDesc, out status, out numSent, out numError);

        groupBox1.Controls[name].Text = orgDesc;
        groupBox1.Controls[stat].Text = status;
        groupBox1.Controls[Sent].Text = numSent;
        groupBox1.Controls[error].Text = numError;

        count++;
    } while (count < 21);
}
```

Query Method:

```
    static void NumSent1(string orgIn, string appIn, out string orgDesc, out string status, out string numSent, out string numError)
    {
        string connString1 = "Server=[IP];Database=Master;Integrated Security=SSPI";

        string query2 = "use SynergyEOM SELECT JobDefID FROM eDistJobs where OrgName = '" + orgIn + "' and App = '" + appIn + "' and Environment = 1";

        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connString1);
        SqlCommand Comm2 = new SqlCommand(query2, Conn);

        Conn.Open();

        string JobDef = Comm2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        string qryOrgDesc = "use [SynEdistDB] Select Orgdesc " +
                        "From JobInstances "+
                        "join [DB1].[SynAdmDB].[dbo].[OrgDef] db1 on JobInstances.OrgID = db1.OrgID " +
                        "where State in (32,64) and DateStarted > DATEADD(d,-30,GETDATE()) and OrgName = '" + orgIn + "' and JobDefID = '" + JobDef + "'";

        string qryState = "use [SynEdistDB] Select State " +
                        "From JobInstances "+
                        "join [DB1].[SynAdmDB].[dbo].[OrgDef] db1 on JobInstances.OrgID = db1.OrgID " +
                        "where State in (32,64) and DateStarted > DATEADD(d,-30,GETDATE()) and OrgName = '" + orgIn + "' and JobDefID = '" + JobDef + "'";

        string qryNumSent = "use [SynEdistDB] Select NumSent " +
                        "From JobInstances "+
                        "join [DB1].[SynAdmDB].[dbo].[OrgDef] db1 on JobInstances.OrgID = db1.OrgID " +
                        "where State in (32,64) and DateStarted > DATEADD(d,-30,GETDATE()) and OrgName = '" + orgIn + "' and JobDefID = '" + JobDef + "'";

        string qryNumError = "use [SynEdistDB] Select NumError " +
                        "From JobInstances "+
                        "join [DB1].[SynAdmDB].[dbo].[OrgDef] db1 on JobInstances.OrgID = db1.OrgID " +
                        "where State in (32,64) and DateStarted > DATEADD(d,-30,GETDATE()) and OrgName = '" + orgIn + "' and JobDefID = '" + JobDef +"'";

        SqlCommand Comm3 = new SqlCommand(qryOrgDesc, Conn);
        SqlCommand Comm4 = new SqlCommand(qryState, Conn);
        SqlCommand Comm5 = new SqlCommand(qryNumSent, Conn);
        SqlCommand Comm6 = new SqlCommand(qryNumError, Conn);

        orgDesc = Comm3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        status = Comm4.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        numSent = Comm5.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        numError = Comm6.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        Conn.Close();
    }
```

Static that works fine

```
    private void Refresh1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string orgIn = org1.Text;
        string appIn = app1.Text;
        string orgDesc, status, numSent, numError;
        NumSent1(orgIn, appIn, out orgDesc, out status, out numSent, out numError);
        name1.Text = orgDesc;
        status1.Text = status;
        Sent1.Text = numSent;
        error1.Text = numError;
    }
```

Comment: What query method? You mean NumSent1? You should post the code for that one also

Comment: This is classic [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) code. Read up a little on how to avoid this issue in whatever framework you are working in. In this case you'd most likely want to use [parameterized queries](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/)

Comment: OK, I get that using a parameterized query is far more secure and I will transition to using stored procedures for this but I do not see how that will solve the issue of how to get and populate the values of these text boxes by iterating through them. Thank you for the security tip.